# I'm currently making a "Happy birthday" website for my friend, and I'm trying to make it so the website slowly appears from top to bottom with opacity

Tags: html, css

I used a 14*21 table and changed the colors of the boxes to write Happy birthday on it, Im struggling to figure out how to make the opacity change from 0 to 1 on each row with a 0.5second difference between each row, I'm trying to do so with transitions because JavaScript is too advanced for me at the moment but I can't seem to get it to work

Html:

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <title> Happy Birthday </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Happy_Birthday.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
        <table class="tablee">
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#1------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr class="Row_1">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#2------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#3------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#4------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#5------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#6------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#7------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#8------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#9------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#10------------------------------------------------------------>
        
        <tr>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#11------------------------------------------------------------>
        
        <tr>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#12------------------------------------------------------------>
        
        <tr>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#13------------------------------------------------------------>
        
        <tr>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#14------------------------------------------------------------>
        
        
        <tr>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        </table>
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------END------------------------------------------------------------>
    
        </body>
        </html>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
    background-color: black;
    }
    
    .tablee {
    width: 100%;
    height: 95vh;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    .Red {
    Background-color: red;
    }
    
    .Blue {
    Background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .Yellow {
    Background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .White {
    Background-color: white;
    }
    
    .Black {
    Background-color: black;
    }
    
    .Orange {
    Background-color: orange;
    }
    
    .Green {
    Background-color: green;
    }
    
    .Lime {
    Background-color: lime;
    }
    
    .Mix_1 {
    Background-color: #FF7400;
    }
    
    .Row_1 {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not a  very pro at CSS animations, but applying animation delay at every table row can make this work

```css
.fade-in{
    animation-name: fade-in;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
}
@keyframes fade-in{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;   
    }
}

tr:nth-child(1){
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
tr:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
tr:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
tr:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
tr:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
tr:nth-child(6){
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
tr:nth-child(7){
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
tr:nth-child(8){
    animation-delay: 4s;
}
tr:nth-child(9){
    animation-delay: 4.5s;
}
tr:nth-child(10){
    animation-delay: 5s;
}
tr:nth-child(11){
    animation-delay: 5.5s;
}
tr:nth-child(12){
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
tr:nth-child(13){
    animation-delay: 6.5s;
}
tr:nth-child(14){
    animation-delay: 7s;
}
body {
    background-color: black;
    }
    
    .tablee {
    width: 100%;
    height: 95vh;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    .Red {
    Background-color: red;
    }
    
    .Blue {
    Background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .Yellow {
    Background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .White {
    Background-color: white;
    }
    
    .Black {
    Background-color: black;
    }
    
    .Orange {
    Background-color: orange;
    }
    
    .Green {
    Background-color: green;
    }
    
    .Lime {
    Background-color: lime;
    }
    
    .Mix_1 {
    Background-color: #FF7400;
    }
```

```html
<table class="tablee">
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#1------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr class="Row_1 fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#2------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr class="fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#3------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr class="fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#4------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr class="fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#5------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr class="fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#6------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr class="fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#7------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr class="fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#8------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr class="fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#9------------------------------------------------------------->
        
        <tr class="fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#10------------------------------------------------------------>
        
        <tr class="fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#11------------------------------------------------------------>
        
        <tr class="fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Mix_1"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#12------------------------------------------------------------>
        
        <tr class="fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Red"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#13------------------------------------------------------------>
        
        <tr class="fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Lime"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------#14------------------------------------------------------------>
        
        
        <tr class="fade-in">
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        <th class="Green"> </th>
        </tr> 
        
        </table>
        <!---------------------------------------------------------------END------------------------------------------------------------>
```